# mpi4py - Slow file read-write in parallel

Tags: python, file-io, mpi

I am trying to separate a huge (*probe*) ascii-format file of size ~15G into smaller formatted (*cloud*) files.

NOTE: Just for reference, the probe and cloud files correspond to the two different ways of sampling data in OpenFOAM, as discussed in [Section 6.3.1](https://doc.cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide-v6/graphs-monitoring) of the user guide.

For this I use mpi4py so that the lines of the probe file can be processed across several processors, with the objective to reduce the overall runtime.

The part of the code where the conversion takes place looks like this (link to full script below):

```py
#- Read line and transform to column
#- Definitions:
#-    nt        = Total number of lines to process
#-    ntPerRank = Number of lines assigned to the current rank
#-    nHeader   = Number of header lines (to skip)
#-    probeFILE = File containing data to be formated
#-    cloudFILE = Output file

timeIndFull = np.arange(nt)
ntPerRank = len(timeIndPerRank)

for i in range(ntPerRank):
    #- Get line number in the probe file assigned to the current rank
    lineInRank = timeIndFull[timeIndPerRank[i]]+nHeader
    
    #- Read the probe file
    with open(probeFILE, 'r') as f:
        for lineNumber, line in enumerate(f):
            if lineNumber == lineInRank:
                #- Split the line and get the relevant elements
                fieldStr = line.split()[1:]
                
                #- Write to cloud file with each element in a new line
                with open(cloudFILE, 'w') as fout:
                    fout.write('\n'.join(fieldStr))
            
            #- Move to the next line in probe file assigned to the current rank
            elif lineNumber > lineInRank:
                break
```

I have an apprehension that this part of the code - i.e. the sequence of file reading, formating, and file writing - can be improved or altered to reduce the overall runtime. I am not sure how as I have very less experience with code optimization so it will be very helpful if you can suggest some points of improvement.

I have shared the full script and a dummy data generator here: https://gist.github.com/nish-ant/170e43d66fcc94ee7bac298f441d51a2

Currently, for the probe file with ~1000 lines to process and each line containing 1000000 elements, the processing time on 64 processors is over 3h45m!

NOTE: The calculations are run on a cluster with Intel® Xeon® Gold SKL-6130 @ 2.1 GHz processors.

To reduce the overall runtime, is it just a matter of increasing the number of processors or is it possible to do the same sequence of operations more efficiently? Thanks.

Comment: Splitting a file is almost certainly not going to be CPU-bound so throwing more cores at the problem is unlikely to speed things up. Instead, the 64 processes are going to contend with each other for access to the storage and result in worse overall performance. You can usually improve file access speeds with large sequential reads and you might want another process or two to do the uploading to the cloud.

Comment: I'd second what @FiddleStix just said.  First, as said above, its almost assuredly *not* CPU bound. You may want to characterize your storage performance before you go down the path of IO optimizations. If you're reading/writing way less than the storage is capable of handling you can probably ignore fancy IO stuff. Second, 15 GB isn't actually *that* big a dataset. Do you have sufficient memory to just read a copy in and work from there? That might also help concretely let you know if reads/writes are actually the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `isslice` from `itertools`. Also, iterating over the entire file for every line number assigned to a rank is O(N²) which is definitely contributing to your runtime woes. Store the targeted line numbers for the rank first. Then, open the file and loop over the list of line numbers. For each line n, retrieve the line with `for line in islice(f, n - 1, n)`. This will increase CPU usage a bit but the significant decrease in runtime should make it a worthwhile trade-off. Hope I didn't miss something since I can't run it.

```py
from itertools import islice

timeIndFull = np.arange(nt)
ntPerRank = len(timeIndPerRank)
linesInRank = [timeIndFull[timeIndPerRank[i]]+nHeader+1 
                    for i in range(ntPerRank)]

def format_line(line):
    #- Write to cloud file with each element in a new line
    with open(cloudFILE, 'w') as fout:
        fieldStr = line.split()[1:]
        fout.write('\n'.join(fieldStr))

#- Option [1] - Using islice
for n in linesInRank:
    with open(probeFILE, 'r') as f:
        for line in islice(f, n-1, n):
            format_line(line)
```

Another option can be to store all the lines to a dictionary:

```py
#- Option [2] - Using dictionary
def get_file_line_dict(lines):
    return {k: v for k, v in enumerate(lines)}
with open(probeFILE, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
fileLines = get_file_line_dict(lines)
for n in linesInRank:
    format_line(fileLines[n])
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea to use `islice`. As you suggested, when I open the file and loop over the list of line numbers, the MPI run exits (without error) with just iterating over the first element of the list `lineNos`. I have no explanation about why it happens. When I change the order, i.e. opening the file within the loop, then all the lines in the list are read. I think you zeroed down on the reason behind the high runtime but I unfortunately don't have a solution to implement it.

Comment: maybe try switching the 'for n in lineNos' and 'with open(probeFILE, 'r') as f' -- I think it might be worth saving all the lines to a dictionary if you dont mind the memory use, which I will add to my post in a sec

Comment: With the dictionary, the job is getting killed by the out-of-memory handler. But the method using `islice` does reduce the overall runtime from 3.7h to 2.8h. So I can accept your answer for the moment (pending edit request) and see if someone else has another suggestion.