# mpi4py - Reading lines of a file in loop

Tags: python, file-io, mpi

This question complements another question that I have posted earlier: [mpi4py - Slow file read-write in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76665399/7473705)

For context, I am trying to read the contents of a file in parallel by scattering the lines across multiple ranks, with the intention to reduce the overall runtime.

As shown in the pseudo-code snippet below, the `for` loop wraps the file `open()` statement.

```py
#- Read line and transform to column
#- Definitions:
#-    nt          = Total number of lines to process
#-    ntPerRank   = Number of lines assigned to the current rank
#-    lineNInRank = List of line numbers in the data file assigned to the current rank
#-    nHeader     = Number of header lines (to skip)
#-    probeFILE   = File containing data to be formated
#-    cloudFILE   = Output file

timeIndFull = np.arange(nt)
ntPerRank = len(timeIndPerRank)
lineNInRank = [timeIndFull[self.timeIndPerRank[i]]+self.nHeader+1
                                for i in range(ntPerRank)]

#- Loop over lines assigned to the current rank
for n in lineNInRank:
    #- Read the probe file
    with open(probeFILE, 'r') as f:
        #- ... do something with line n ...
```

This works as for each rank, the script loops over all the lines assigned to it. But I am apprehensive that this might be slow in comparison to opening the file once and looping over the lines.

So something like this where the `for` loop is now wrapped inside the `open()` statement:

```py
#- Read the probe file
with open(probeFILE, 'r') as f:
    #- Loop over lines assigned to the current rank
    for n in lineNInRank:
        #- ... do something with line n ...
```

This fails as the MPI run exits (without error) with just iterating over the first line number in the list `lineNInRank`.

For the sake of completeness, I have also mentioned this in the comment to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76666114/7473705).

I am not sure what is causing this behavior but it will be nice to have a working solution to test if I gain significant reduction in runtime. Thanks.

PS: The full script and a dummy data generator can be found here: https://gist.github.com/nish-ant/170e43d66fcc94ee7bac298f441d51a2

EDIT 1: I just came across the [MPI.File](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/mpi4py.MPI.File.html) class. But I cannot find a tutorial to understand how to implement it. Could something like `MPI.File.Read`, `MPI.File.Read_all` or `MPI.File.Read_at_all` would make the file accessible to all the ranks?

EDIT 2: I found a [tutorial](https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2014/spring/12300-1/labs/lab3/) for MPI I/O but it relies on byte offset instead of line numbers.

Comment: MPI parallel IO and text files do not go well together.